# How to keep sequence of numbers until certain row number reached

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been trying to assign numbers with sequence. I would like to further add to repeat the sequence until the *certain* row numbers reached. For example repeat the sequence for every 44th row.

Here is what I mean

```
test_table <- data.frame(col=rep(0:10,each=11),  row=c(rev(0:10)))
```

and assigning cumulative numbers in this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50079515/assigning-the-number-in-new-column-based-on-row-count)

```
> library(dplyr)
 test_table%>%
 mutate(No=(row_number() - 1) %/% 11)

test_table  
        col row No
    1     0  10  0
    2     0   9  0
    3     0   8  0
    4     0   7  0
    5     0   6  0
    6     0   5  0
    7     0   4  0
    8     0   3  0
    9     0   2  0
    10    0   1  0
    11    0   0  0
    12    1  10  1
    13    1   9  1
    14    1   8  1
    15    1   7  1
    16    1   6  1
    17    1   5  1
    18    1   4  1
    19    1   3  1
    20    1   2  1
    21    1   1  1
    22    1   0  1
    23    2  10  2
    24    2   9  2
    25    2   8  2
    26    2   7  2
    27    2   6  2
    28    2   5  2
    29    2   4  2
    30    2   3  2
    31    2   2  2
    32    2   1  2
    33    2   0  2
    34    3  10  3
    35    3   9  3
    36    3   8  3
    37    3   7  3
    38    3   6  3
    39    3   5  3
    40    3   4  3
    41    3   3  3
    42    3   2  3
    43    3   1  3
    44    3   0  3
    45    4  10  4
    46    4   9  4
    47    4   8  4
    48    4   7  4
    49    4   6  4
    50    4   5  4
    51    4   4  4
    52    4   3  4
    53    4   2  4
    54    4   1  4
    55    4   0  4
    56    5  10  5
    57    5   9  5
    58    5   8  5
    59    5   7  5
    60    5   6  5
    61    5   5  5
    62    5   4  5
    63    5   3  5
    64    5   2  5
    65    5   1  5
    66    5   0  5
    67    6  10  6
    68    6   9  6
    69    6   8  6
    70    6   7  6
    71    6   6  6
    72    6   5  6
    73    6   4  6
    74    6   3  6
    75    6   2  6
    76    6   1  6
    77    6   0  6
    78    7  10  7
    79    7   9  7
    80    7   8  7
    81    7   7  7
    82    7   6  7
    83    7   5  7
    84    7   4  7
    85    7   3  7
    86    7   2  7
    87    7   1  7
    88    7   0  7
    89    8  10  8
    90    8   9  8
    91    8   8  8
    92    8   7  8
    93    8   6  8
    94    8   5  8
    95    8   4  8
    96    8   3  8
    97    8   2  8
    98    8   1  8
    99    8   0  8
    100   9  10  9
    101   9   9  9
    102   9   8  9
    103   9   7  9
    104   9   6  9
    105   9   5  9
    106   9   4  9
    107   9   3  9
    108   9   2  9
    109   9   1  9
    110   9   0  9
    111  10  10 10
    112  10   9 10
    113  10   8 10
    114  10   7 10
    115  10   6 10
    116  10   5 10
    117  10   4 10
    118  10   3 10
    119  10   2 10
    120  10   1 10
    121  10   0 10
```

Ok. Good! But I would like to keep the sequence for example `0 and 1` until the 44th row reached. After that, start to the new sequence from `2` and go 88th row like this.

So the expected output will be

```
test_table  
      col row No
    1     0  10  0
    2     0   9  0
    3     0   8  0
    4     0   7  0
    5     0   6  0
    6     0   5  0
    7     0   4  0
    8     0   3  0
    9     0   2  0
    10    0   1  0
    11    0   0  0
    12    1  10  1
    13    1   9  1
    14    1   8  1
    15    1   7  1
    16    1   6  1
    17    1   5  1
    18    1   4  1
    19    1   3  1
    20    1   2  1
    21    1   1  1
    22    1   0  1
    23    2  10  0
    24    2   9  0
    25    2   8  0
    26    2   7  0
    27    2   6  0
    28    2   5  0
    29    2   4  0
    30    2   3  0
    31    2   2  0
    32    2   1  0
    33    2   0  0
    34    3  10  1
    35    3   9  1
    36    3   8  1
    37    3   7  1
    38    3   6  1
    39    3   5  1
    40    3   4  1
    41    3   3  1
    42    3   2  1
    43    3   1  1
    44    3   0  1
    45    4  10  2
    46    4   9  2
    47    4   8  2
    48    4   7  2
    49    4   6  2
    50    4   5  2
    51    4   4  2
    52    4   3  2
    53    4   2  2
    54    4   1  2
    55    4   0  2
    56    5  10  3
    57    5   9  3
    58    5   8  3
    59    5   7  3
    60    5   6  3
    61    5   5  3
    62    5   4  3
    63    5   3  3
    64    5   2  3
    65    5   1  3
    66    5   0  3
    67    6  10  2
    68    6   9  2
    69    6   8  2
    70    6   7  2
    71    6   6  2
    72    6   5  2
    73    6   4  2
    74    6   3  2
    75    6   2  2
    76    6   1  2
    77    6   0  2
    78    7  10  3
    79    7   9  3
    80    7   8  3
    81    7   7  3
    82    7   6  3
    83    7   5  3
    84    7   4  3
    85    7   3  3
    86    7   2  3
    87    7   1  3
    88    7   0  3
    89    8  10  4
    90    8   9  4
    91    8   8  4
    92    8   7  4
    93    8   6  4
    94    8   5  4
    95    8   4  4
    96    8   3  4
    97    8   2  4
    98    8   1  4
    99    8   0  4
    100   9  10  5
    101   9   9  5
    102   9   8  5
    103   9   7  5
    104   9   6  5
    105   9   5  5
    106   9   4  5
    107   9   3  5
    108   9   2  5
    109   9   1  5
    110   9   0  5
    111  10  10  4
    112  10   9  4
    113  10   8  4
    114  10   7  4
    115  10   6  4
    116  10   5  4
    117  10   4  4
    118  10   3  4
    119  10   2  4
    120  10   1  4
    121  10   0  4
```

How can we do that ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean `No` should only have values 0 and 1?

Comment: no please check the expected output!

Comment: Ah. I am sorry. I didn't notice the scroll bar.

Comment: Is this how your actual data set looks like though?

Comment: nope. This is just a reproducible example.

Comment: but I have the same decreasing number and sequence in cols. numbers are different so please don't count on them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it in more general way

```
num.seq = 11L            # total number of sequences in the first column
num.rows = N * num.seq   # total number of rows
seq.length.3 = 44        # length of the pattern in the 3rd column

# number of paterns in the 3rd column
num.seq.3 = ( num.rows - 1 )  %/% seq.length.3 +1   

# starting number in the sequence of the 3rd column
nseq=0

# vector for the 3rd column (could be done right in data frame def.)             
No = (rep(rep( nseq:(nseq+1), each = N, times= 2), times=num.seq.3) + 
      rep(0:(num.seq.3 -1)*2, each= seq.length.3)) [1:num.rows]

test_table <- data.frame(col=rep(0:10,each=11),  
                         row=c(rev(0:10)),
                         No=No)
```

An alternative way:

```
library(dplyr)
dt2 <- test_table%>%
  mutate(No = (row_number() - 1) %/% 11) 
dt2$No <- dt2$No %% 2 + (rep(0:num.seq.3, each =44, times=num.seq.3 )*2) 
          [1:num.rows]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess it is too complicated. There should be another way to this ?

Comment: I guess I am a little bit lost of what you are trying to achieve. Is the third column related to the first 2 at all? It looks like you are trying to use mutate() function which means that you are trying to make third column to be a function of the first one.. Does the row number to "stop" the sequence in the third column (44) is always divisible by 11? Does the number of rows in the final data frame is always divisible by the pattern length (11)?

Comment: yes everything is divisible in the data to 11. third column is not related directly. I rather would like to use row number as reference.

Comment: if it is too complicated you can cut last 11 rows.

Comment: Just added one more way to do it. As for cutting out the last 11 rows, I think it would be easier to add 11 more rows to make the total number of rows (at the moment 121) to be divisible by 4 (132), then everything can be simplified even further.

Answer (score 1):

The arithmetic, which is totally dependent on row numbers, seems right this way.

```
test_table%>%
  mutate(No=((row_number() - 1) %/% 11) %% 2) %>% # alternating 11 rows of 0's and 1's 
  mutate(No = No + ((row_number() - 1) %/% 44) * 2) # add 2 every after 44 rows
```

Here is the result, as intended.

```
structure(list(col = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L), row = c(10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 
6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 10L, 
9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 0L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 10L, 9L, 
8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L), No = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("col", "row", 
"No"), row.names = c(NA, -121L))
```

Answer (score 0):

This would deliver what I understand to be the requested vector (except I think your sequencing"skipped a beat"):

```
 c( rep( c(1,2,1,2), each=11) , rep(c(3,4,3,4), each=11), rep(c(5,6,5,6), each=11) )
  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3
 [48] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5
 [95] 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
```

A more general way:

```
c( sapply( seq(1, 6, by=2), function(start) { 
                                    rep( rep(start:(start+1) , 2), each=11) }))
```

The outer c() will remove the matrix character that sapply defaults to.